# How to cut Pandas Series with non-unique bin edges?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of about 200000 values, >50% of which are NaN and 0. Ideally, I'd like to bin my values using `qcut()`, but that gives me an error due to non-unique bin edges. How would I categorize all the NaN values in fractile 1 and 0 values in fractile 2, and then the rest of the non-zero values in fractile labels 3 to 10 (assuming I want 10 fractiles)

Answer (score 0):

You can feed qcut an array specifying the distribution (the example in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) is [0, .25, .5, .75, 1.] for quantiles. As such, first fill the NaNs with -1 to make sure they show up. Then specify an array of buckets with this distribution:

```
[0,
count(-1)/df.shape[0],
(count(-1)+count(0))/df.shape[0],
(count(-1)+count(0))/df.shape[0] + 1.*(df.shape[0] - count(-1)+count(0))/7,
(count(-1)+count(0))/df.shape[0] + 2.*(df.shape[0] - count(-1)+count(0))/7,
#...
1]
```